# SeekBar in ListView Item is reset

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

In my application I have a ListView with a custom Item view. Each Item has an own SeekBar which holds the age from the different Persons which are displayed in the ListView. My problem is that I can scroll the SeekBar for each person but if the Item is scrolled out and came in next time the SeekBar is reseted to 0. My CustomAdapter looks like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    View row = convertView;
    PeopleHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new PeopleHolder();

        final TextView tvAge = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.Age);
        tvNote.setTag(position);

        holder.age = (SeekBar) row.findViewById(R.id.agekBar); 
        holder.age.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){   }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){   }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
            {
                    tvAge.setText("" + progress);
            }
        }); 

        holder.name  = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.Name);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (PeopleHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    People p = data.get(position);

    holder.name.setText(p.getFullName());
    holder.age.setProgress(p.getAge());

    return row;
}

private static class PeopleHolder
{
    TextView name;
    SeekBar age;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure to change the value of the person's age when the progress changes:

```
    // adding a final int that can be accessed from inside the listener
    final int personPosition = position;
    holder.age.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
    {
        ...

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
        {
                tvAge.setText("" + progress);
                // change the age of the person in data
                data.get(personPosition).setAge(progress);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I thought about this too and I found out with a Toast that the position varaible is for the first and the third item 0. How can that be? Because of this the solution does not work :/

Comment: Toasts can be hard to associate with actual events because of the delay and how long they stay on the screen.  Instead try adding 
`Log.i("age list", "position: " + position);` at the very beginning of getView(), then use the log to see which positions are actually being accessed.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way ListViews work - when a view is scrolled off the screen, it's destroyed or recycled to show another entry in the list. As the SeekBar is changed, you'll need to keep a note of what the value was somewhere else (e.g. a Map in your Activity or Fragment) and set the value every time the view is created.